# Can't find google adwords api

Tags: google-ads-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I try to use `google.adwords` api, but it seems not there.

code:

```js
import { Router } from "express";
import { google } from "googleapis";

function adwords() {
  const router = Router();

  router.get("/adwords", (req, res) => {
    const googleAdwords = google.adwords;
  });
  return router;
}

export { adwords };
```

But I found `google adwords` scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords`) at here 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#scope

How can I use `google adwords` API using `google-api-nodejs-client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adwords API is not supported by `google-api-nodejs-client`, see [this list of supported ones](https://apis-nodejs.firebaseapp.com/) for reference.

You can find the list of official client libraries for the Google Adwords API [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries). Unfortunately, JS does not have a Google-maintained client library at the moment.

Comment: Sadly to hear it.

Comment: The new [Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start) is a REST/gRPC based service, so it should be easier to access it using JS. It's still in beta, tough.